# Querying Firestore using 2 where clause in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

- I have two attributes in my `eventClick` table `eventID` and `userID` so what I am trying to do is if `eventID` and `userID` normally exists then show `You have already clicked` if not then make an entry of the click. I thought of using two clause and merging it but that just resulted in insertion of the values.
- I am trying using the below code

```
final checkSnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('eventClick')
  .where('eventID', isEqualTo: eventID)
  .where('userID', isEqualTo: userID)
  .snapshots();
```

- I want the working to be like

```
  if (checkSnapshot.exists) {
      print('already exists');
    } else {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('eventClick').add({
        'eventID': eventID,
        'eventName': eventName,
        'eventImageUrl': eventImageUrl,
        'userID': userID
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using [.get()](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) ? That should return a [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) which has a 'size' property. If 0, that means no such document exists.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('eventClick')
  .where('eventID', isEqualTo: eventID)
  .where('userID', isEqualTo: userID)
  .get()
  .then((checkSnapshot) {
    print(checkSnapshot.docs[0]);
    if (checkSnapshot.size > 0) {
      print("Already Exists");
    } else {
      //add the document
    }
  });
```

Comment: It is getting added to the table if it exists the query is not working the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: @LavSharma I've move the snapshot out of if block, could you share a screenshot of that?

Comment: A `QuerySnapshot` does not have a `data()` method.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that @RenaudTarnec, I missed the `.docs[0]`.

Comment: ```checkSnapshot.size()``` is basically returning the number of entries in my ```eventClick``` table
Image showing entires -[Image 1](https://ibb.co/54zRTXJ)
Image from firestore - [Image 2](https://ibb.co/PT3Hjvk), [Image 3](https://ibb.co/McbzBmg)

Comment: @LavSharma if the snapshot size is greater than 0 then it should print 'Already Exists' else it will add the document. Can you please confirm all those 3 documents have different eventId? I doubt if you have accidentally added multiple copies using same IDs

Comment: @LavSharma yes I just confirmed it using 2 screenshots that you've shared. They have same userID and eventID. Please delete the duplicates.

Comment: Ohh my fault I used the ```==``` instead of ```>=``` solved now

Comment: @LavSharma I had that == too in first go :')

Comment: Make that ```>=``` to ```>``` as ```>=``` is not allowing it to register as it will return 0 if it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('task')
                .where('usergroup', isEqualTo: 'software')
                .where('userid', isEqualTo: 'ep434334')
                .snapshots(),
```